# Best place to ask question regarding hacking Amazon Fire phone feature

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Specifically, the question is that:

How to override the long hold center button feature of the Amazon Fire phone?

Because it always triggers the annoying "Hello" lady and usually she will say "I did not get that" in my pocket. That usually freaks me out. There is a temporary way to disable it, but once it's disabled when you long press it will trigger a "yes or no" window, which many many many times, my accidental press will turn on this nightmare lady again. I really need a way to disable this. I can install apps from the Google Play Store as well, so if there is any app does that will be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions about the Amazon Fire are on-topic at [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com):

- https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-fire-phone

This kind of "how do I change this default behavior on my device" question is spot-on for that site. Of course, like most of the rest of Stack Exchange, a question for an app recommendation will be off-topic. Stick to asking *how* to do what you want.